# How can I use gsutil with multiple accounts?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I frequently use Google Cloud Storage with at least two accounts: personal@gmail.com and work@corp.com.  I used `gsutil config` to create `.boto` files for both accounts, which I've renamed to `personal.boto` and `work.boto`.

It is tiring to have to remember to type `cp personal.boto ~/.boto` whenever I need to switch between these accounts. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is as follows:

```
$ BOTO_CONFIG=/path/to/personal.boto gsutil cp #...
```

For more detailed variations on this theme see [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gs-discussion/UMjqPKUNg6k/discussion).

Answer (score 61):

[The Google Cloud SDK](https://developers.google.com/cloud/sdk/gcloud) now includes the `gcloud` tool, which allows you to login and easily switch between accounts.

```
$ gcloud auth list
Credentialed accounts:
 - youremail@gmail.com (active)
To set the active account, run
 $ gcloud config set account <account>
```

To login to another account, simply run `$ gcloud auth login` and use another Google account.

Answer (score 11):

For this, use following command to switch to the account you want.

```
gcloud auth login
```

This will take you to the Google account switch page which can be used to switch to the relevant user.

Comment: That’s already in [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21208930/735926) written more than 4 years earlier.

Answer (score -1):

under windows OS:
set BOTO_CONFIG=E:\.boto & e:\gsutil\gsutil.py ls s3://your_bucket/folder

The "E:" is hard driver id in Windows OS. If you have no "E:", just put the full path of your ".boto" file to try.

Comment: Looks like you probably want to add a little more explanation of what this does. Right now, if anyone runs this, 1. it wont work for them, since they dont have E:, 2. without any explanation, they don't know what E: should be.